# Crossbow draw strength

Tags: bow-hunting

My crossbow has a 50LB draw. It has no mechanism to decrease the amount of strength you use to cock it (you literally just grab the string and pull it back). So my question is: "If the draw is 50LB (and it has no mechanism or system to aid you in cocking it) does it require 50LBs of strength to pull it back? You see I am considering installing a new draw on it that will be stronger and I need to know if I will be able to cock it.

Comment: My daughter aged around 12, IIRC, could cock my 100lb crossbow - she may have been younger. Obviously she wasn't legally permitted to do so anywhere remotely public! It isn't one with a stirrup, either. She isn't weak by any standard but it pretty much top effort. Hopefully this offers a rough guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - 50lbs draw means you need to be able to pull 50lbs, unless you have a pulley/gear reduction.

So if you increase to a higher draw, you'll need to be able to pull it.

Answer (score 5):

If you have to pull it back manually without a mechanism then you will need the strength to pull it back. Also consider when putting a new draw on it, that the body can hold the increased vibration and tension without shattering. I would suggest going for a new crossbow if you want increased poundage, or get a professional to change it for you.

As a side note, it depends on what you want to do with it. If you are gallery 50lbs is enough. If outside target then I wouldn't say any more than 100lb. If you have hunting in mind I would suggest 150lb for small game, or 175lb for larger. Unless you plan to take down a bear you won't need to go any higher.